# jQuery ui dialog trigger event after dialog created

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, dialog

I am trying to trigger the function `setupCheckBox('chk-img');` after the jQuery ui dialog is created but I cannot crack it. Any help is appreciated!

I have tried both open and create events (which I bind at the start of my code):

```
jQuery("#TicketTC").on( "dialogcreate", function( event, ui ) {
    setupCheckBox('chk-img');
});
```

and

```
jQuery("#TicketTC").on( "dialogopen", function( event, ui ) {
    setupCheckBox('chk-img');
});
```

My dialog code is:

```
jQuery("#TicketTC").dialog({
    modal: true,
    width: 600,
    height: 'auto',
    autoOpen: true,
    buttons: {
        CONTINUE: function() {
            jQuery(this).dialog("close");
            return true;
        },
        CANCEL: function() {
            jQuery(this).dialog("close");
            return false;
        }
    }
}).html('<div class="support-msg">' + tempHTML + '</div>');
```

Comment: Do you  wait for DOM ready before binding the events?

Comment: Hi @PeterKA, yes, I have added an `alert("HERE!");` line to the `dialogcreate/open` bindings and it triggers OK just prior to the dialog showing on the screen. I am trying to execute the code (essentially custom checkboxes) after the dialog opens, but both seem to trigger as it opens and as such the HTML with the `checkboxes` is not yet added to the DOM so the checkBoxes code does not work.

Comment: Would you be able to create a jsfiddle demo to demonstrate the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dialog(...)` opens the dialog immediately. So the html you set afterwards using `html` is not in the dialog. And bind to the `dialogopen` event.

```
jQuery("#TicketTC")
  .on("dialogopen", function (event, ui) {
    setupCheckBox('chk-img');
  })
  .html('<div class="support-msg"></div>')
  .dialog({
    modal: true,
    width: 200,
    height: 'auto',
    autoOpen: true,
    buttons: {
      CONTINUE: function () {
        jQuery(this).dialog("close");
        return true;
      },
      CANCEL: function () {
        jQuery(this).dialog("close");
        return false;
      }
    }
  });
```

Comment: Thanks @lloiser. I think I will need a JSFiddle to help you help me! I will do one next. Your suggestion makes sense in terms of sequence but it now has a strange behavior. On first and second dialog open (without page refresh) it does not work, but it works on the third dialog open?! Madness! I will do a JSFiddle to see what I learn in the process.

Answer (score 1):

You should bind the event handlers before the dialog is initialized since the dialog is set to open by default (*If you bind the event afterwards it'll not be invoked since both the events already happened*).

Rather than binding the events manually, Initializing the widget with the callbacks will be safer method:

```
jQuery("#TicketTC").on("dialogcreate", function (event, ui) {
   setupCheckBox('chk-img');
});
jQuery("#TicketTC").on("dialogopen", function (event, ui) {
   setupCheckBox('chk-img');
});
jQuery("#TicketTC").dialog({
   modal: true,
   width: 200,
   height: 'auto',
   autoOpen: true,
   create: function (event, ui) { // this is more reliable
      setupCheckBox('chk-img');
   },
   buttons: {
    CONTINUE: function () {
        jQuery(this).dialog("close");
        return true;
    },
    CANCEL: function () {
        jQuery(this).dialog("close");
        return false;
    }
  }
}).html('<div class="support-msg"></div>');
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rv4rx0me/1/)

Comment: Hi @TJ it still does not work. I was getting the Alerts myself too (see my comment for @PeterKA). It seems the code that generates the checkboxes is just out of sync with the HTML being created by the dialog. I will create a fiddle and place here. I need sleep now, 5AM in Sydney... Thanks for the help!!

Comment: @TheRealPapa ok I'll try modifying the answer once you share the fiddle :)

Comment: As a matter of fact I placed an ALERT inside `setupCheckBox()` and it triggers prior to the dialog opening, so there is no HTML for it to execute against. I think I need something like `afterOpen` listener.